# Reading MANY files at once in Fortran

Tags: file-io, fortran

I have 500,000 files which I need to read in Fortran and each file has ~14,000 entries in it (each entry is only about 100 characters long). I need to process each line for each file at a time. For example, I need to process line 1 for all 500,000 files before moving on to line 2 from the files and so forth.

I cannot open them all at once (I tried making an array of file pointers and opening them all) because there will be too many files open at once. Instead, I would like to do something as follows:

```
 do iline = 1,Nlines
   do ifile = 1,Nfiles
     ! open the file
     ! read a line
     ! close the file
   enddo
 end
```

In hopes that this would allow me to read one line at a time (from each file) and then move on to the next line (in each file). Unfortunately, each time I open the file it starts me off at line 1 again. Is there any way to open/close a file and then open it again where you left off previously?

Thanks

Comment: I think the title is a bit misleading since the question is not about actually opening all these files at the same time.  It also seem to be a surprisingly non-sophisicated way to manage such large amount of files and data.  Have you considered setting up a database management system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [fseek](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FSEEK.html) and  [ftell](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FTELL.html#FTELL) in something like the following.

```
! initialize an array of 0's
do iline = 1,Nlines
   do ifile = 1,Nfiles
     ! open the file
     ! fseek(fd, array(ifile))
     ! read a line
     ! array(ifile)=ftell(fd)
     ! close the file
   enddo
 end
```

The (untested) idea is to store the offset of each file in an array and position the cursor at that place upon opening the file. Then, once a line is read, the `ftell` retrieves the current position which is saved to memory for next round. If all entries have the same length, you can spare the array and just store one value.

Comment: Brilliant. Before I tried this I went with a poor man's `FSEEK` by just searching for the designated line with reads. It took ~8 minutes to do it for 10 files but now that time got dropped down to ~4 seconds with `FSEEK`

Comment: Not standard Fortran however.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it is not possible in this way in standard Fortran. Even If you specify

```
position="ASIS"
```

the actual position will be unspecified for a not already connected unit and will be in fact the beginning of the file on most systems.

That means You have to use

```
  read(*,*)
```

enough times to get on the right place in the file.

You could also use `stream` access. The file would be again opened at the beginning, but you can use

```
  read(u,*,pos=n) number
```

where `n` is the position saved from the previous open. You can get the position from

```
inquire(unit=u, pos=n)
n = n
```

You would open the file with `acess="STREAM"`.

Also 500000 opened files is indeed too much. There are ways how to inquire for the system limits and how to control them, but also your compiler may have some limits http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/

Other solution: Couldn't you store the content of the files in memory? Today couple of Gigabytes is OK, but it may be not enough for you.

Comment: the contents of all data is over 130 GB. I can't store it into memory or that would be a simple fix. I am actually reading it like this because all the data was in one file and I had to read it in a way which would have taken ~4.5 years to finish! So yes, I can change the algorithm and the current build is the best option so far!

Comment: You may also try the `stream` access, but it may not be any faster.

Answer (score 0):

If the files have fixed, i.e., constant, record lengths, you could use direct access. Then you could "directly" read a specific record.   A big "if" however.

Answer (score 0):

the overhead of all the file opening/closing will be a big performance bottleneck.
You should try to read as much as you can for each open operation given whatever memory you have:

pseudocode:

```
          loop until done:
            loop over all files:
                open
                fseek !as in damiens answer
                read N lines into array ! N=100 eg.
                save ftell value for file
                close
            end file loop
            loop over N output files:
                open
                write array data
                close
```